# Angular SwPush.notificationClicks does not receive data object

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, service-worker, azure-notificationhub

I am currently working on an Angular project and implementing push notifications using the SwPush service. I have successfully subscribed to the SwPush.message event and I'm able to receive all the data that I have sent. However, I'm facing an issue with the SwPush.notificationClicks event. When I subscribe to it, I do not receive the data object associated with the notification.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe((c) => {
      this.logger.log('PUSH NOTIFICATION CLICKED', c);
    });

    this.swPush.messages.subscribe((c) => {
      this.logger.log('PUSH MESSAGE RECEIVED', c);
    });
```

Here's a response of both subscription

```
{ // this.swPush.messages
    "data": {
        "property2": "42",
        "property1": "value1"
    },
    "from": "55851556555",
    "priority": "normal",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Hub Test Notification",
        "body": "This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs."
    },
    "fcmMessageId": "ID"
}


{ //this.swPush.notificationClicks
    "action": "",
    "notification": {
        "actions": [],
        "badge": "",
        "body": "This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs.",
        "data": null,
        "dir": "auto",
        "icon": "",
        "lang": "",
        "renotify": false,
        "requireInteraction": false,
        "silent": false,
        "tag": "",
        "timestamp": 1688476171195,
        "title": "Notification Hub Test Notification",
        "vibrate": []
    }
}
```

I subscribe to the SwPush.notificationClicks event. However, when I log the event object in the callback, data object that was sent with the notification is null.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if there is a different approach I should take to access the data object when a notification is clicked.

Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Tried to create custom service worker and added methods to listen notification clicks, results were same I had full event but notification property had same object

Comment: Hope push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs reference [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial)

Comment: ```this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log('Notification event', event);```

Comment: unfortunately response is same


this is what my request looks like 
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body"
  },
  "webpush": {
    "notification": {
      "title": "title",
      "body": "body"
    },
    "data": {
      "value1": "text",
      "value2": "",
      "value3": "sample3",
      "value4": "sample4"
    },
    "fcm_options": {
      "link": "https://dummypage.com"
    }
  },
  "to": "deviceToken"
}